# Swift range-slider not working properly. Can't find the bug

Tags: ios, swift, touch, cgcontext

I have this range slider that i rewrote from swift 3.0 to swift 2.2 - but something went wrong - I just cant seem to find the problem. So now I'm sharing it with you guys :)

The problem is, that I'm only able to drag one of the thumbs, and only 1 time, and then everything is stuck.

My demo project can be found here: https://github.com/nharbo/RangeSliderSwift2.2
It's only 2 classes, so if you have time, I would love you to have a look at it!

Also, here's the code from one of the classes, which I suspect is the one making trouble:

```
/// Range slider track layer. Responsible for drawing the horizontal track
public class RangeSliderTrackLayer: CALayer {

/// owner slider
weak var rangeSlider: NHRangeSlider?

/// draw the track between 2 thumbs
///
/// - Parameter ctx: current graphics context
public override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
    super.drawInContext(ctx)
    guard let slider = rangeSlider else {
        return
    }

    // Clip
    let cornerRadius = bounds.height * slider.curvaceousness / 2.0
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath)

    // Fill the track
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, slider.trackTintColor.CGColor)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath)
    CGContextFillPath(ctx)

    // Fill the highlighted range
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, slider.trackHighlightTintColor.CGColor)
    let lowerValuePosition = CGFloat(slider.positionForValue(slider.lowerValue))
    let upperValuePosition = CGFloat(slider.positionForValue(slider.upperValue))
    let rect = CGRect(x: lowerValuePosition, y: 0.0, width: upperValuePosition - lowerValuePosition, height: bounds.height)
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect)
}
}

/// the thumb for upper , lower bounds

public class RangeSliderThumbLayer: CALayer {

/// owner slider
weak var rangeSlider: NHRangeSlider?

/// whether this thumb is currently highlighted i.e. touched by user
public var highlighted: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/// stroke color
public var strokeColor: UIColor = UIColor.grayColor() {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/// line width
public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 0.5 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/// draw the thumb
///
/// - Parameter ctx: current graphics context
public override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
    super.drawInContext(ctx)
    guard let slider = rangeSlider else {
        return
    }

    let thumbFrame = bounds.insetBy(dx: 2.0, dy: 2.0)
    let cornerRadius = thumbFrame.height * slider.curvaceousness / 2.0
    let thumbPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: thumbFrame, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

    // Fill
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, slider.thumbTintColor.CGColor)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, thumbPath.CGPath)
    CGContextFillPath(ctx)

    // Outline
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, strokeColor.CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, lineWidth)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, thumbPath.CGPath)
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx)

    if highlighted {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.1).CGColor)
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, thumbPath.CGPath)
        CGContextFillPath(ctx)
    }
}
}

/// Range slider view with upper, lower bounds
@IBDesignable
public class NHRangeSlider: UIControl {

// MARK: properties

/// minimum value
@IBInspectable public var minimumValue: Double = 0.0 {
    willSet(newValue) {
        assert(newValue < maximumValue, "NHRangeSlider: minimumValue should be lower than maximumValue")
    }
    didSet {
        updateLayerFrames()
    }
}

/// max value
@IBInspectable public var maximumValue: Double = 100.0 {
    willSet(newValue) {
        assert(newValue > minimumValue, "NHRangeSlider: maximumValue should be greater than minimumValue")
    }
    didSet {
        updateLayerFrames()
    }
}

/// value for lower thumb
@IBInspectable public var lowerValue: Double = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        if lowerValue < minimumValue {
            lowerValue = minimumValue
        }
        updateLayerFrames()
    }
}

/// value for upper thumb
@IBInspectable public var upperValue: Double = 100.0 {
    didSet {
        if upperValue > maximumValue {
            upperValue = maximumValue
        }
        updateLayerFrames()
    }
}

/// stepValue. If set, will snap to discrete step points along the slider . Default to nil
@IBInspectable public var stepValue: Double? = nil {
    willSet(newValue) {
        if newValue != nil {
            assert(newValue! > 0, "NHRangeSlider: stepValue must be positive")
        }
    }
    didSet {
        if let val = stepValue {
            if val <= 0 {
                stepValue = nil
            }
        }

        updateLayerFrames()
    }
}

/// minimum distance between the upper and lower thumbs.
@IBInspectable public var gapBetweenThumbs: Double = 2.0

/// tint color for track between 2 thumbs
@IBInspectable public var trackTintColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0) {
    didSet {
        trackLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/// track highlight tint color
@IBInspectable public var trackHighlightTintColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.45, blue: 0.94, alpha: 1.0) {
    didSet {
        trackLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/// thumb tint color
@IBInspectable public var thumbTintColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
    didSet {
        lowerThumbLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
        upperThumbLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/// thumb border color
@IBInspectable public var thumbBorderColor: UIColor = UIColor.grayColor() {
    didSet {
        lowerThumbLayer.strokeColor = thumbBorderColor
        upperThumbLayer.strokeColor = thumbBorderColor
    }
}

/// thumb border width
@IBInspectable public var thumbBorderWidth: CGFloat = 0.5 {
    didSet {
        lowerThumbLayer.lineWidth = thumbBorderWidth
        upperThumbLayer.lineWidth = thumbBorderWidth
    }
}

/// set 0.0 for square thumbs to 1.0 for circle thumbs
@IBInspectable public var curvaceousness: CGFloat = 1.0 {
    didSet {
        if curvaceousness < 0.0 {
            curvaceousness = 0.0
        }

        if curvaceousness > 1.0 {
            curvaceousness = 1.0
        }

        trackLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
        lowerThumbLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
        upperThumbLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/// previous touch location
private var previouslocation = CGPoint()

/// track layer
private let trackLayer = RangeSliderTrackLayer()

/// lower thumb layer
public let lowerThumbLayer = RangeSliderThumbLayer()

/// upper thumb layer
public let upperThumbLayer = RangeSliderThumbLayer()

/// thumb width
private var thumbWidth: CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(bounds.height)
}

/// frame
override public var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        updateLayerFrames()
    }
}

// MARK: init methods
override public init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initializeLayers()
}

required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    initializeLayers()
}

// MARK: layers

/// layout sub layers
///
/// - Parameter of: layer
public override func layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    super.layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer)
    updateLayerFrames()
}

/// init layers
private func initializeLayers() {
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    trackLayer.rangeSlider = self
    trackLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    lowerThumbLayer.rangeSlider = self
    lowerThumbLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    layer.addSublayer(lowerThumbLayer)

    upperThumbLayer.rangeSlider = self
    upperThumbLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    layer.addSublayer(upperThumbLayer)
}

/// update layer frames
public func updateLayerFrames() {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

    trackLayer.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: bounds.height / 3)
    trackLayer.setNeedsDisplay()

    let lowerThumbCenter = CGFloat(positionForValue(lowerValue))
    lowerThumbLayer.frame = CGRect(x: lowerThumbCenter - thumbWidth / 2.0, y: 0.0, width: thumbWidth, height: thumbWidth)
    lowerThumbLayer.setNeedsDisplay()

    let upperThumbCenter = CGFloat(positionForValue(upperValue))
    upperThumbLayer.frame = CGRect(x: upperThumbCenter - thumbWidth / 2.0, y: 0.0, width: thumbWidth, height: thumbWidth)
    upperThumbLayer.setNeedsDisplay()

    CATransaction.commit()
}

/// thumb x position for new value
public func positionForValue(value: Double) -> Double {
    if (maximumValue == minimumValue) {
        return 0
    }

    return Double(bounds.width - thumbWidth) * (value - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue)
        + Double(thumbWidth / 2.0)
}

/// bound new value within lower and upper value
///
/// - Parameters:
/// - value: value to set
/// - lowerValue: lower value
/// - upperValue: upper value
/// - Returns: current value
public func boundValue(value: Double, toLowerValue lowerValue: Double, upperValue: Double) -> Double {
    return min(max(value, lowerValue), upperValue)
}

// MARK: - Touches

/// begin tracking
public override func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    super.beginTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)

    // set highlighted positions for lower and upper thumbs
    if lowerThumbLayer.frame.contains(previouslocation) {
        lowerThumbLayer.highlighted = true
    }

    if upperThumbLayer.frame.contains(previouslocation) {
        upperThumbLayer.highlighted = true
    }

    return lowerThumbLayer.highlighted || upperThumbLayer.highlighted
}

/// update positions for lower and upper thumbs
public override func continueTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    super.continueTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)

    let location = touch.locationInView(self)

    // Determine by how much the user has dragged
    let deltaLocation = Double(location.x - previouslocation.x)
    var deltaValue: Double = 0

    if (bounds.width != bounds.height) {
        deltaValue = (maximumValue - minimumValue) * deltaLocation / Double(bounds.width - bounds.height)
    }

    previouslocation = location

    // if both are highlighted. we need to decide which direction to drag
    if lowerThumbLayer.highlighted && upperThumbLayer.highlighted {

        if deltaLocation > 0 {
            // left to right
            upperValue = boundValue(upperValue + deltaValue, toLowerValue: lowerValue + gapBetweenThumbs, upperValue: maximumValue)
        }
        else {
            // right to left
            lowerValue = boundValue(lowerValue + deltaValue, toLowerValue: minimumValue, upperValue: upperValue - gapBetweenThumbs)
        }
    }
    else {

        // Update the values
        if lowerThumbLayer.highlighted {
            lowerValue = boundValue(lowerValue + deltaValue, toLowerValue: minimumValue, upperValue: upperValue - gapBetweenThumbs)
        } else if upperThumbLayer.highlighted {
            upperValue = boundValue(upperValue + deltaValue, toLowerValue: lowerValue + gapBetweenThumbs, upperValue: maximumValue)
        }
    }

    // only send changed value if stepValue is not set. We will trigger this later in endTracking
    if stepValue == nil {
        sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    }

    return true
}

/// end touch tracking. Unhighlight the two thumbs
public override func endTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.endTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)

    lowerThumbLayer.highlighted = false
    upperThumbLayer.highlighted = false

    // let slider snap after user stop dragging
    if let stepValue = stepValue {
        lowerValue = round(lowerValue / stepValue) * stepValue
        upperValue = round(upperValue / stepValue) * stepValue
        sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the rest of the expected functionality, but the thumbs stop dragging after the first try because you are checking the thumb positions against the previouslocation variable instead of the current touch position in the beginTracking method in NHRangeSlider.swift. If you modify the method as follows, you can drag the thumbs as many times as you want (but I don't know how the rest of the functionality is affected by this since you'll need to see how this affects the previouslocation variable):

```
open override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        super.beginTracking(touch, with: event)

        print("beginTrackingWithTouch")

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        // set highlighted positions for lower and upper thumbs
        if lowerThumbLayer.frame.contains(location) {
            print("1111")
            lowerThumbLayer.highlighted = true
        }

        if upperThumbLayer.frame.contains(location) {
            print("2222")
            upperThumbLayer.highlighted = true
        }

        return lowerThumbLayer.highlighted || upperThumbLayer.highlighted
    }
```

**Note:** The code is in Swift 3.0 format since I do not have Swift 2.x installed.

Comment: Okay, this helped quite a lot! Thanks! The problem is not, that the upperThumb is movine just as I tap it. It moves with my finger when i drag, but it acts a little weird from the first touch. It moves to the left, just by a touch.. Any ide about why? :-) And again, thanks! This is already so much better!!

Comment: Happy that it helped :) Of course, if it was useful, could you please give a "correct answer"? 

It's evening here, so will take a look at the code tomorrow morning and let you know about the first touch ... My suspicion would be that you are setting the frame for the thumbs somewhere. So take a look to see if that is the issue?

Comment: yes of course! I will accept your answer :) And please, if you know about the last part, I would be so happy! I'll have a look at that you said, but it would be awesome id you would too :) Have a lovely day! :))

Comment: I took a look and while I'm not sure that this is the only issue, one issue is for the jumping you saw is "previouslocation" handling. In "continueTracking" you get the drag distance by getting the difference between the current touch location and "previouslocation" but you do not set "previouslocation" when touches begin in "beginTracking" :) Fix that and it should work better :)

Comment: awesome!! Thanks a lot mate! I really appreciate it :))

Comment: Happy to have been of help :) Good luck with the code!